# How to do Division in a Fractional Calculator?

Tags: c#, calculator

I'm completely unsure on how to do it. I've searched but can't find a simple answer.

I've done the multiplication and I know its similar to it. Need some help. I want to know how to do division for two fractions.

My Multiply module:

```
    {

        answerDenominator = num1Denominator * num2Denominator; //Multiply both denominators
        answerNumerator = ((num1Whole * num1Denominator) + num1Numerator) *   //multiply the whole number by the denominator and add the numerator to it
                ((num1Whole * num2Denominator) + num2Numerator); //multiply the whole number by the second denominator, then add the second numerator, multiply these two answers together

        answerWhole = answerNumerator / answerDenominator; 
        answerNumerator = answerNumerator % answerDenominator;

    }
```

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/fractions/div-fractions-fractions/v/conceptual-understanding-of-dividing-fractions-by-fractions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let that we have to make the following division:

```
(a/b):(c/d)
```

This is equal to

```
(a/b)*(d/c)
```

That being said the division can simply be done like below:

```
static double CalculateDivisionResult(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    return (a/b)*(d/c);
}
```

In the above:

- `a` is the num1Numerator.
- `b` is the num1Denominator.
- `c` is the num2Numerator.
- `d` is the num2Denominator.

The most important thing that you should pay attention on the above is the fact that we use `double`. Why we do so?

Let that `a=3`, `b=7`, `c=4` and `d=5`:

Then

```
(a/b)*(d/c) = 15/28
```

If you had chosen to represent your number as integers, `int a=3`, then the above would be obvious 0. Representing them as doubles we can overcome this.